# ActiveMQ: Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58090 failed: java.io.EOFException

Tags: tcp, activemq-classic

At the startup of ActiveMQ we're facing this issue :

```
2022-07-18 14:02:48,968 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58090 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58090@61616
2022-07-18 14:02:48,972 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58094 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58094@61616
2022-07-18 14:02:48,976 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58098 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58098@61616
2022-07-18 14:02:48,983 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58102 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58102@61616
2022-07-18 14:02:48,994 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58106 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58106@61616
2022-07-18 14:02:49,009 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58114 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58114@61616
2022-07-18 14:02:49,009 | WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:58110 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:58110@61616
```

We thought that they are related to disk space as it was over 90%, but even after expanding the disk space we're still facing the same issue!

OS: Ubuntu

**Update:**

we're using the PIM solution [`contentserv`](https://contentserv.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCU/overview) from `Atlassian`

Comment: What does this has to do with `Elasticsearch` ? I feel you need to provide more information to understand the issue

Comment: What is the functional impact of this WARN message? Do you have clients failing to connect to ActiveMQ? If so, are they on stable network connections?

Answer (score 0):

These are WARN messages that have no impact on message flow. These messages indicate some clients are disconnecting without fully cleaning up resources and calling .close(). Check with your app teams' code to make sure they are not leaking connections, or not properly closing resources.